# Android Bluetooth Service Freezes Screen?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am trying to solve the problem I have when developing a bluetooth connection application. Ideally the app should automatically connect with the bluetooth device, start the service and read the data in `MainActivity`. Right now when the device is online, everything works perfectly. The problem is: when the device is offline, it will take about 8 seconds before the app cancels its service, and this process will freeze the screen even if I explicitly put the `doBindService()`in a separete thread.

public class BluetoothManager {

```
private static final String TAG = BluetoothManager.class.getName();
private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

public static BluetoothSocket connect(BluetoothDevice dev) throws IOException{

    BluetoothSocket sock = null;
    BluetoothSocket socketFallback = null;
    Log.d(TAG,"Start Bluetooth Connection...");
    try
    {
        sock = dev.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
        Log.d(TAG, "Probably gonna wait here...");
        sock.connect();
    }catch (Exception e1){
        Log.e(TAG, "There was an error while establishing Bluetooth connection, Failing back...", e1);

    }
    return sock;
}
```

}

So I made a stand-alone app out of my main app [here](https://github.com/wilsonandusa/AndroidBluetoothDemo), which only contains bluetooth connection function. Could anyone please take a look at the project and any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add pernissions in mainefest**

package="com.example.sairamkrishna.myapplication" >

```
  android:allowBackup="true"

  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

  android:label="@string/app_name"

  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <activity

     android:name=".MainActivity"

     android:label="@string/app_name" >


     <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

     </intent-filter>

  </activity>
```

Comment: which permission should I add?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

Comment: Bluetooth Parmission

Comment: if you go to the github link in my question you can see I did have these permissions in my project, and the screen only freezes while the device is offline, it works perfectly when the device is powered, so  I do not think adding permisson will help with the multithreading problem...